# two strings should be different length but are counted as same length

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm running into an issue with a pair of strings. Toward the bottom of my first function I test the length of both strings, and even though searchingForLength should be less than half the size of searchedLength, they are the same "length". What is going on here?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool findString(const char searched[], const char searchingFor[]) {
    int i, j, k = 0, searchedLength = sizeof(searched)/sizeof(searched[0]), searchingForLength = sizeof(searchingFor)/sizeof(searchingFor[0]);

    bool in = false;

    for (i = 0; i < searchedLength; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < searchingForLength; j++) {
            if (searched[i] == searchingFor[j]) {
                k++;
                if (k == searchingForLength) {
                    in = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", k);
    printf("%d\n",searchingForLength);
    printf("%d\n",searchedLength);
    if (in == true) {
        printf("Yes\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("No\n");
    }
    return in;
}

int main (void) {

    const char searched[] = { 'I', ' ', 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e', ' ', 'p', 'i', 'e' };
    const char searchingFor[] = { 'l', 'i', 'k', 'e' };

    findString(searched, searchingFor);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sizeof` is an operator and it gives the size of the type of it's argument, which is not the length of a string.

For arrays it gives the size of the array in bytes, to calculate the length of a string you need `strlen()`, but none of your arrays are strings, and hence you can't use `strlen()`, they are not strings in a c string sense.

A string in c, is a sequence of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte, your arrays don't have a terminating `nul`, so the `str*` functions can't handle them properly.

A simple implementation of `strlen()` would be

```
size_t strlen(const char *string)
 {
     size_t length;
     length = 0;
     while (*string++ != '\0')
         length++;
     return length;
 }
```

as you can see, if there is no `'\0'` or `nul` byte<sup>1</sup> in the data, the function will keep iterating beyond the end of the string, what happens after that is undefined.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>They are the same and their value is `0`</sub>

Comment: May I suggest that you selectively `s/string/array/` in the places where you're referring to "a string that isn't a string"? That way this answer will make that much more sense.

Answer (score 3):

Sizeof is evaluated at compile time, and in this case it will return the size of a pointer (`char[]` is more or less a `char*`). You should use `strlen` instead.

Oh and as it has been mentioned, you strings are not zero-terminated, so that won't really work either. You should define your strings as

```
const char blah[] = "whee"
```

Comment: By the way, that array declaration does not require `const`, you can perfectly do `blah[0] = 'x';`

Comment: Right you are of course, but it rarely hurts to make stuff const if they should not change :)

Comment: Sure, and it also doesn't guarantee that it will not change anyway since you as the programmer in c, are almighty.